# Passing voice objects instead of strings to speech synthesis

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks to [@Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6331369/ivan) I have a simple code to select the speech synthesis voices via checkboxes:

```js
// Get the voice select element.
const select_US = document.querySelector('.select_US');
const select_UK = document.querySelector('.select_UK');
let selected_voices;

// Fetch the list of voices and populate the voice options at the beginning of the course
function loadVoices() {
  // Fetch the available voices.
  let voices_US = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) {
    return voice.lang == 'en-US';

  });

  //console.log(voices_US); //outputs array of voice objects

  const checkboxes_US = voices_US.map(function(name) {

    const html = `
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="${name}" name="${name}">
      <label for="${name}">${name.name}</label>
    </div>
  `.trim();

    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.innerHTML = html;

    const element = select_US.appendChild(wrapper.firstChild);
    return element.querySelector('input');

  });

  //You have 3 seconds to select voices via checkboxes
  setTimeout(function() {

    selected_voices = checkboxes_US.filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked).map(checkbox => checkbox.name);

    console.log(selected_voices);

  }, 3000)

}

// Execute loadVoices.
loadVoices();

// Chrome loads voices asynchronously.
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function(e) {
  loadVoices();
};

// Create a new utterance for the specified text and add it to
// the queue.
function speak(text) {
  // Create a new instance of SpeechSynthesisUtterance.
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  msg.voice = selected_voices[0];

  // Set the text.
  msg.text = text;

  // Queue this utterance.
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

// after 5 seconds initiate speech synthesis
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Speaking..');
  speak('This is a simple example text here!');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div class="select_US">
</div>
```

The expected behavior is that the user has 3 seconds to select the voices via checkboxes..

User can select as many voices as he/she wants but we only want the first voice in the array:

```
msg.voice = selected_voices[0];
```

If `selected_voices` contains the voice objects the code would work correctly but, there is a problem with it. When I log it:

[image]

It seems like string elements inside the array!

Instead, we should see:

[image]

I think that `selected_voices` is the problem, it fails to provide the correct value.

How can I fix that? I can't find a solution without a hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see (part) of the problem, log the HTML that you generated:

```
<div class="select_US">
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]" name="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]">
      <label for="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]">Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)</label>
    </div><div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]" name="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]">
      <label for="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]">Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)</label>
    </div><div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]" name="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]">
      <label for="[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]">Google US English</label>
    </div></div>
```

See the `[object SpeechSynthesisVoice]`s? When you do

```
  let voices_US = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) {
    return voice.lang == 'en-US';

  });
```

`voices_us` becomes an array of voices. But then when you do

```
voices_US.map(function(name) {
```

what `name` holds is actually a *voice*, not a string, which is a big part of the problem. This is one reason why precise variable names are important. Let's call the parameter `voice` instead, and use its `name` property to get at the string.

Then, once the timeout callback runs, `.find` one of the checkboxes which is checked. If there is one, take its `name` (a string), and `.find` in the voices array the voice with the same name. Then you can assign that found voice to `voiceInstance` and use `msg.voice = voiceInstance;` inside `speak`.

You should also only run the main part of `loadVoices` once, to otherwise you'll continually create new inputs.

```js
'use strict';

// Get the voice select element.
const select_US = document.querySelector('.select_US');
const select_UK = document.querySelector('.select_UK');
let voiceInstance;

// Fetch the list of voices and populate the voice options at the beginning of the course
function loadVoices() {
  // Fetch the available voices.
  const voices_US = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(voice => voice.lang == 'en-US');
  if (!voices_US.length || voiceInstance) {
    // Chrome; voices haven't loaded yet, or a voice is already selected
    return;
  }
  const checkboxes_US = voices_US.map(function(voice) {
    const { name } = voice;
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `
      <input type="checkbox" id="${name}" name="${name}">
      <label for="${name}">${name}</label>
    `;
    select_US.appendChild(div);
    return div.querySelector('input');
  });

  //You have 3 seconds to select voices via checkboxes
  setTimeout(function() {
    const checkbox = checkboxes_US.find(checkbox => checkbox.checked);
    if (!checkbox) {
      console.log('Not fast enough');
      return;
    }
    const name = checkbox.name;
    voiceInstance = speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(voice => voice.name === name);
  }, 3000)

}

// Execute loadVoices.
loadVoices();

// Chrome loads voices asynchronously.
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = loadVoices;

// Create a new utterance for the specified text and add it to
// the queue.
function speak(text) {
  if (!voiceInstance) {
    // No instance to use to speak with
    return;
  }
  // Create a new instance of SpeechSynthesisUtterance.
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  msg.voice = voiceInstance;

  // Set the text.
  msg.text = text;

  // Queue this utterance.
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

// after 5 seconds initiate speech synthesis
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Speaking..');
  speak('This is a simple example text here!');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div class="select_US">
</div>
```

The logic would probably be easier to follow, without relying on global variable reassignment, if each timeout called the next:

```js
'use strict';

if (!window.chrome) {
  loadVoices();
} else {
  // Chrome loads voices asynchronously.
  window.speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', loadVoices, { once: true });
}

function loadVoices() {
  const allVoices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  const voices_US = allVoices.filter(voice => voice.lang == 'en-US');
  const select_US = document.querySelector('.select_US');
  const checkboxes_US = voices_US.map(function(voice) {
    const { name } = voice;
    const div = select_US.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    div.innerHTML = `
      <input type="checkbox" id="${name}" name="${name}">
      <label for="${name}">${name}</label>
    `;
    return div.querySelector('input');
  });

  //You have 3 seconds to select voices via checkboxes
  setTimeout(function() {
    const checkbox = checkboxes_US.find(checkbox => checkbox.checked);
    if (!checkbox) {
      console.log('Not fast enough');
      return;
    }
    const name = checkbox.name;
    const voiceInstance = speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(voice => voice.name === name);
    console.log('Voice found...');
    setTimeout(speak, 2000, 'This is a simple example text here!', voiceInstance);
  }, 3000)
}

function speak(text, voice) {
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  msg.voice = voice;
  msg.text = text;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

```html
<div class="select_US">
</div>
```